# Google Apps Script to Create Confluence Page -- Results in Status Code 500

Tags: google-apps-script, confluence-rest-api

Note: I also posted this question on the Atlassian forum here:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Google-Apps-Script-to-Create-Confluence-Page-HTTP-500-Error/qaq-p/1039040#M66094

I'm reaching out to a larger audience here on SO.

I'm using the following google apps script code in a Google Sheet to create a Confluence page:

```
headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + 
pswd), "Content-Type": "application/json"};

url = "https://confluence.asdf.com/rest/api/content/";
var params = { 
  "method":"POST",
  "headers":headers,
  "muteHttpExceptions": false,
  "type":"page",
  "title":newTitle,
  "space":{"key":"DOC"},
  "body":{"storage":{"value": "<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>" }, 
  "representation":"storage"} 
};
var createResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

However, when I submit the request, I receive this response:

```
Request failed for https://confluence.atlas.asdf.com/rest/api/content/ 
returned code 500.
Truncated server response: {"statusCode":500,"
message":"<?> No content to map to Object due to end of 
input","reason":"Internal Server Error"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to 
examine full response)
```

I realize there are curl samples out there which I've seen but do not help me.
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: 25-March**
@Tanaike
I modified the code as you suggested:

```
    headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pswd) };


    var payload = {
      "type": "page",
      "title": newTitle,
      "space": {"key": "DOC"},
      "body": {
        "storage": {
          "value": "<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>"
        },
        "representation": "storage"
      }
    };
    var params = { 
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": headers,
      "muteHttpExceptions": false,
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
      "contentType": "application/json"
    };

    var createResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

I receive the same error as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `params` as follows and test again. From the error message in your question, the request body was put in the property of `payload`.

```
var payload = {
  "type": "page",
  "title": newTitle,
  "space": {"key": "DOC"},
  "body": {
    "storage": {
      "value": "<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>"
    },
    "representation": "storage"
  }
};
var params = { 
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": headers,
  "muteHttpExceptions": false,
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that each value in `payload` and `headers` is correct.
- `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in headers can be also put in `params` as `"contentType": "application/json"`.

#### References:

- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Confluence REST API examples](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Manipulatingcontent)

I cannot test this modification. So if this didn't work, can you provide the error message? I would like to think of about the issue.

### Edit:

From [the official document](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Manipulatingcontent), it seems that the property of `body` is `"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}`. So please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pswd) };
var payload = {
  "type": "page",
  "title": newTitle,
  "space": {"key": "DOC"},
  "body": {
    "storage": {
      "value": "<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>",
      "representation": "storage" // Modified
    }
  }
};
var params = { 
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": headers,
  "muteHttpExceptions": false,
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
  "contentType": "application/json"
};
var createResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I could confirm that the result was the same with the result from the official sample script. If this didn't work, please confirm each value of `payload` and `headers`, again.

Comment: @Steve Murphy I apologize for the inconvenience. I noticed that there is an issue at the property of ``body``. So could you please confirm it?

Comment: I implemented your changes and the script works. Just one issue:
When I create the page it is visible only in my Dashboard and from there I need to move it to the correct child page in the desired space. (This is not optimal.)
How do I create the page such that it is placed in a child page in the space?

Comment: @Steve Murphy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 1st issue was resolved. About your new issue, can you post it as new question? Because your initial question is to remove the error of your script, and your new issue is related to the specification of the API. This is different from 1st one. So please close this question and post your new issue as new question. When you post the new question, please include the detail information. By this, it will be useful for other users who has the same issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: To place the page in the desired location, add this to the payload: "ancestors":[{"id":<parent page ID>}], And thank you for helping me. I really appreciate the time you took.!

Comment: This is the closest I found to my problem, but instead of creating a confluence page, I would like to get a confluence page based on ID and get the result in Json format so I can parse the confluence body content. @SteveMurphy would you provide some hint on how to do it? Thanks