# Get Content of a Confluence page with Apps Script and parse its content

Tags: google-apps-script, confluence-rest-api

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308969/google-apps-script-to-create-confluence-page-results-in-status-code-500) for creating a new page in confluence, but not a specific one for getting the content of a confluence Cloud page, based on ID for example in Google App Script and being able to parse the content of the body of the page, for example, parsing a JSON result or maybe using Confluence REST-API to get the content of specific object.

I adapted the source code from the mentioned question as follow:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const url = "https://<company>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/<ID>";
  const token = "<token>";
  const user = "<email>";

  headers = { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + token) };
  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": false,
    "contentType": "application/json"
  };

  let createResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(createResponse.getContentText());

}
```

where `<xxxx>` are specific parameters related to my account. `<ID>` is Confluence document ID.

I am following [REST API specification for Confluence Cloud](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/api-group-content/#api-wiki-rest-api-content-id-get)

I am getting a response, but it provides general property about the page.

Changing the url to the following:

```
https://<company>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/<ID>?expand=body.storage
```

adding the following suffix: `?expand=body.storage`

it generates the content, but it is difficult to parse:

```
{"id":"2020706439","type":"page","status":"current","title":"Onboard Resource Template for 
more than one resource","macroRenderedOutput":{},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<ac:structured-macro ac:name=
\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"756d4d54-7492-49ac-b502-19d1a740ea92\"><ac:rich-text-body><p>
To use it, please make a copy of this template and replace the title with Resource Name(s) and add the 
onboarding date as a suffix</p></ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><table data-layout=\"wide\">
<colgroup><col style=\"width: 182.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 144.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 148.0px;\" />
<col style=\"width: 143.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 137.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 142.0px;\" />
</colgroup><tbody><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#6fa8dc\" colspan=\"6\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">
<strong>New&nbsp;Resource&nbsp;(s) Onboarding&nbsp;Information and Tracking</strong></p></td></tr>
<tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Information&nbsp;Provided&nbsp;by&nbsp;Vendor</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 1</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\">
<p>Resource 2</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 3</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\">
<p>Resource 4</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 5</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>First&nbsp;
Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Last&nbsp;
Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Address</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Phone&nbsp;Number</p></td><td>
<p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>E-Mail</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>WFH&nbsp;or&nbsp;W@Office</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Location (if W@Office)</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Role</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Start&nbsp;Date</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>End&nbsp;Date</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Phone&nbsp;Number</p></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Manager's&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Team</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\" colspan=\"6\">
<p>Information&nbsp;Provided&nbsp;by&nbsp;Onboarding Manager</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>New&nbsp;Resource&nbsp;ID</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>New&nbsp;
Resource&nbsp;Company&nbsp;E-mail</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Cost&nbsp;Center</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Laptop&nbsp;Serial&nbsp;Number</p></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\">
<p><ac:inline-comment-marker ac:ref=\"377a17e3-a869-451f-a58b-19cac76916a4\">Access&nbsp;Requests&nbsp;by&nbsp;
Rosana</ac:inline-comment-marker></p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">
Ticket&nbsp;Number</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Date&nbsp;</p><p style=\"text-align: center;\">
Submitted</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p>SNOW Assignee</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">
Ready&nbsp;in<ac:inline-comment-marker ac:ref=\"269ae226-6036-4ede-9720-d3c25f5d31d2\">&nbsp;</ac:inline-comment-marker>(n)-Days</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Date Completed</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Company&nbsp;ID&nbsp;Request</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Laptop</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Slack</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td>
<p>Outlook</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>WebEx</p></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ping</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#a2c4c9\" colspan=\"6\"><p>Access&nbsp;Request&nbsp;by&nbsp;
Program Manager (or a PM on his behalf)</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>SNOW Access and Timesheets</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#f4cccc\" colspan=\"6\">
<p>Access Request/Action by&nbsp;David&nbsp;Leal</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Access to Jira/Confluence</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p>Jira Admin</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>Resource&nbsp;Plan</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p>Snow Manager</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr>
<tr><td><p><em>Actions</em></p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#f4f5f7\" colspan=\"5\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">
<em> Date Completed</em></p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"text-align: right;\">Add to Slack&nbsp;Channels</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr>
<td><p style=\"text-align: right;\">Add to JIRA&nbsp;Projects</p></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr>
<tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Access&nbsp;Requests&nbsp;by&nbsp;Tech Lead</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Ticket Number</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Date Submitted</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>SNOW Assginee</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Ready in Days</p></td>
<td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Date Completed</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>AWS&nbsp;Work&nbsp;Space&nbsp;(VDI)</p></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>GitLab</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>AWS Console</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td>
<td><p /></td></tr></tbody></table><p />",
"representation":"storage","embeddedContent":[],"_expandable":{"content":"/rest/api/content/2020706439"}},
"_expandable":{"editor":"","atlas_doc_format":"","view":"","export_view":"","styled_view":"","dynamic":"",
"editor2":"","anonymous_export_view":""}},"extensions":{"position":158},"_expandable":{"childTypes":"","container":
"/rest/api/space/PDC","metadata":"","operations":"","schedulePublishDate":"","children":"/rest/api/content/2020706439/child",
"restrictions":"/rest/api/content/2020706439/restriction/byOperation","history":"/rest/api/content/2020706439/history",
"ancestors":"","version":"","descendants":"/rest/api/content/2020706439/descendant","space":
"/rest/api/space/PDC"},"_links":{"editui":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=2020706439","webui":
"/spaces/PDC/pages/2020706439/Onboard+Resource+Template+for+more+than+one+resource","context":"/wiki",
"self":"https://<company>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/2020706439","tinyui":"/x/h4hxe","collection":
"/rest/api/content","base":"https://pan-american.atlassian.net/wiki"}}
```

the content I would like to get is part of a confluence table like this one:
[image]

Here the following question in regard to this problem:

1. Is this the best approach to get Confluence page content in order to parse it?, for example using the option: `expand=body.storage` or on contrary there are better ways to get the content of Confluence page (or specific table), so it is easier to parse.
2. If the content obtained is the best way to do it, then is there any HTML table javascript library or tool or script to parse the table content?

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize my answer is not useful for your situation. About your question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike I would need to know what are your questions related to my post. The question assumes some context: Confluence is a product from Atlassian (documentation tool), it provides a way to get information via API, so we should be able to obtain the information in a POST call and get the information from Apps Script, usually a JSON object that we would be able to parse the content of the confluence page.

Comment: So try making a call to the api with urlFetchApp and see what you get.  We prefer dealing with scripting questions.  It's best if you try write the script yourself to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper I edited my question adding the Javascript code I adapted from the mentioned questions. I am getting a 404 eror.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your current script, it seems that your question is different from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55308969/7108653). In your current situation, can you provide the official document of the method of the API you want to use? And, have you ever tested your API with other method except for Google Apps Script?

Comment: Added more details to my question, I was able to get a response from REST API, but the information I am getting it is difficult to parse, I am wondering if there is a better way to obtain the information so it can be easier parse.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your current question? About your additional information, from `it generates the content, but it is difficult to parse:`, in this case, your initial question of `<status-code>404</status-code>` was resolved and you changed your question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct @Tanaike the question in the post is still valid, because I would like to find a way to parse the content too, but initially I could not get a response, the URL was not properly created, fixed that, the rest remains, how to parse the content returned in an easier way. The only way I could think of is parsing the HTML content via regular expression, or may be Confluence provides a more friendly output that I am not visualizing now or some HTLM parser. If you recommend to create another question, I can do it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current question. From `the question in the post is still valid`, your current question is to resolve the error of `<status-code>404</status-code>` when your script is used. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your feedback, I updated my initial post, see the questions at the end of the post. I was able to get a response, now the question is in order to parse the content confluence page, is this the best response format from Confluence?, if so, then what are the option to parse the HTML table content. I see you have a blog entry about getting the content of an HTML table in Google Spreadsheet, maybe this is the best or good enough way to accomplish it: https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/08/01/parsing-html-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to parse the HTML from the sample value (`it generates the content, but it is difficult to parse:`) in your question and put them to the sheet.

  - You have already been able to retrieve the value from the API you want to use.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this case, I would like to propose using Sheets API. The pasteData of Sheets API can parse the HTML table.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, this script uses Sheets API. So [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the sheet name. And run the function. By this, the Sheets API parses the HTML table and puts to the sheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const obj = { "id": "2020706439", "type": "page", "status": "current", "title": "Onboard Resource Template for more than one resource", "macroRenderedOutput": {}, "body": { "storage": { "value": "<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"756d4d54-7492-49ac-b502-19d1a740ea92\"><ac:rich-text-body><p>To use it, please make a copy of this template and replace the title with Resource Name(s) and add the onboarding date as a suffix</p></ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><table data-layout=\"wide\"><colgroup><col style=\"width: 182.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 144.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 148.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 143.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 137.0px;\" /><col style=\"width: 142.0px;\" /></colgroup><tbody><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#6fa8dc\" colspan=\"6\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>New&nbsp;Resource&nbsp;(s) Onboarding&nbsp;Information and Tracking</strong></p></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Information&nbsp;Provided&nbsp;by&nbsp;Vendor</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 1</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 2</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 3</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 4</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#ff9900\"><p>Resource 5</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>First&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Last&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Address</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Phone&nbsp;Number</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>E-Mail</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>WFH&nbsp;or&nbsp;W@Office</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Location (if W@Office)</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Role</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Start&nbsp;Date</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>End&nbsp;Date</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Vendor's&nbsp;Phone&nbsp;Number</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Manager's&nbsp;Name</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Team</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\" colspan=\"6\"><p>Information&nbsp;Provided&nbsp;by&nbsp;Onboarding Manager</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>New&nbsp;Resource&nbsp;ID</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>New&nbsp;Resource&nbsp;Company&nbsp;E-mail</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Cost&nbsp;Center</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Laptop&nbsp;Serial&nbsp;Number</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p><ac:inline-comment-marker ac:ref=\"377a17e3-a869-451f-a58b-19cac76916a4\">Access&nbsp;Requests&nbsp;by&nbsp;Rosana</ac:inline-comment-marker></p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Ticket&nbsp;Number</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Date&nbsp;</p><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Submitted</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p>SNOW Assignee</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Ready&nbsp;in<ac:inline-comment-marker ac:ref=\"269ae226-6036-4ede-9720-d3c25f5d31d2\">&nbsp;</ac:inline-comment-marker>(n)-Days</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#b6d7a8\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\">Date Completed</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Company&nbsp;ID&nbsp;Request</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Laptop</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Slack</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Outlook</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>WebEx</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ping</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#a2c4c9\" colspan=\"6\"><p>Access&nbsp;Request&nbsp;by&nbsp;Program Manager (or a PM on his behalf)</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>SNOW Access and Timesheets</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#f4cccc\" colspan=\"6\"><p>Access Request/Action by&nbsp;David&nbsp;Leal</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Access to Jira/Confluence</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p>Jira Admin</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>Resource&nbsp;Plan</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p>Snow Manager</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p><em>Actions</em></p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#f4f5f7\" colspan=\"5\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\"><em> Date Completed</em></p></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"text-align: right;\">Add to Slack&nbsp;Channels</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p style=\"text-align: right;\">Add to JIRA&nbsp;Projects</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Access&nbsp;Requests&nbsp;by&nbsp;Tech Lead</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Ticket Number</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Date Submitted</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>SNOW Assginee</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Ready in Days</p></td><td data-highlight-colour=\"#fff2cc\"><p>Date Completed</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>AWS&nbsp;Work&nbsp;Space&nbsp;(VDI)</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>GitLab</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>AWS Console</p></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td><td><p /></td></tr></tbody></table><p />", "representation": "storage", "embeddedContent": [], "_expandable": { "content": "/rest/api/content/2020706439" } }, "_expandable": { "editor": "", "atlas_doc_format": "", "view": "", "export_view": "", "styled_view": "", "dynamic": "", "editor2": "", "anonymous_export_view": "" } }, "extensions": { "position": 158 }, "_expandable": { "childTypes": "", "container": "/rest/api/space/PDC", "metadata": "", "operations": "", "schedulePublishDate": "", "children": "/rest/api/content/2020706439/child", "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/2020706439/restriction/byOperation", "history": "/rest/api/content/2020706439/history", "ancestors": "", "version": "", "descendants": "/rest/api/content/2020706439/descendant", "space": "/rest/api/space/PDC" }, "_links": { "editui": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=2020706439", "webui": "/spaces/PDC/pages/2020706439/Onboard+Resource+Template+for+more+than+one+resource", "context": "/wiki", "self": "https://<company>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/2020706439", "tinyui": "/x/h4hxe", "collection": "/rest/api/content", "base": "https://pan-american.atlassian.net/wiki" } };
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
  const requests = [{ pasteData: { data: obj.body.storage.value, html: true, coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests}, ss.getId());

  // When you want to retrieve the values as an array, please use the following script.
  // const array = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // console.log(array)
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script uses your sample value. So when the structure of the value is changed, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.
- I can confirm that this script works fine when I use your sample value. So when you tested this script for your actual value, when an error occurs, please check the retrieved value again.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tanaike, it is a very elegant solution and generic. The only drawback I see it requires to create a temporary sheet that needs to be deleted after getting the array with the values. I accomplished the same but with more line of codes using regular expressions. I will post it here. If I am not getting any other solution, I will consider yours as the valid one. I looks like there is no other alternative than getting the content using: `expand=body.storage`

Comment: @David Leal Thank you for replying. I thought that Sheets API is the strong parser for HTML data. And, in this case, if the structure of HTML data is changed, this might be able to continue to be used. So I proposed this. But it seems that this method is not suitable for your situation. I deeply apologize for this. But I think that this method might be useful for other users. So I would like to leave this. I apologize for this again.

Comment: not at all @Tanaike. I accepted your response as the correct one. It is more generic and situable for a variety of scenarios. At the time you responded I had this solution almost complete. Otherwise I would had use your solution for my problem. Thanks a lot for your interest on helping me and for your solution, it opens to me to Sheets API. I will take into consideration in future situations.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution using regular expressions to extract the information from `createResponse.getContentText()`. It is less generic than the solution @Tanaike provided, but it doesn't require to generate an auxiliar tab (sheet) on active Spreadsheet that needs to be removed after getting all the records:

```
/*
@param id {String} Confluence ID page 
*/
function getOnboardRecords(id) {
  const URL = https://<COMPANY>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/%s?expand=body.storage;
  const TOKEN = "Provide the token";
  const USER = "Provide user name, i.e an email";
  // Relevant columns to get the information
  const ROW_NAMES = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", 
    "E-Mail", "Role", "Start Date", "End Date", "Vendor's Name",
    "Team", "New Resource ID","New Resource Company E-mail"];

  function parsePhone(s) {
    let ss = s.replace(/[ \(\)\-+]/g, "");
    return (ss.length == 10) ? "1" + ss : ss; // Adding US code
  }

  function parseDate(d) {
    let dateRegEx = new RegExp(/<time datetime=\\"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\\" ?\/>/);
    return d.match(dateRegEx)[1];
  }

  function parseEmail(e) {
    let s = e.replaceAll(/<.*?>|<\/.*?>/g, "");
    let validEmailRegEx = new RegExp(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/);
    const NON_VALID_EMAIL = "The input argument: '%s' is not a valid email";
    if (!validEmailRegEx.test(s)) throw new Error(Utilities.formatString(NON_VALID_EMAIL, result));
    return s;
  }


  let headers = { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USER + ':' + TOKEN) };
  let params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": false,
    "contentType": "application/json"
  };

  let url = Utilities.formatString(URL, id);
  let createResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  let content = createResponse.getContentText();
  let tableRegEx = new RegExp("<table.*?>(.*?)</table>");
  let tableHtml = content.match(tableRegEx)[0];
  let rowRegEx = new RegExp("<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>", "g");
  let rowsResult = tableHtml.match(rowRegEx);
  let colRegExp = new RegExp("<td.*?>(.*?)</td>", "g");
  let values = new Map();
  rowsResult.forEach(function (item) { // parsing each column of given row
    item = item.replace(/<p>|<\/p>|<p ?\/>/g, "").replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
    let row = [];
    [...item.matchAll(colRegExp)].forEach(item => row.push(item[1])); // Getting the group (.*?)
    row = row.filter(function (item) { return item != ""; }); // Keep non empty string only
    let key = ROW_NAMES.find(it => it == row[0]);
    if (key) {
      if (row.length > 1) {
        let records = row.slice(1);
        if (key == ROW_NAMES[2]) { // phone number
          records.forEach(function (item, index) {
            this[index] = parsePhone(item);
          }, records);
        }
        if ((key == ROW_NAMES[5]) || (key == ROW_NAMES[6])) {
          records.forEach(function (item, index) {
            this[index] = parseDate(item);
          }, records);
        }
        if ((key == ROW_NAMES[3]) || (key == ROW_NAMES[10])) {
          records.forEach(function (item, index) {
            this[index] = parseEmail(item);
          }, records);
        }
        values.set(key, records);
      }
    }

  });
  return values;
}
```

I am parsing specific values for each row, because of the format Confluence has on my specific onboard Confluence Template.

Invoking the function with specific Confluence ID:

```
let onboardValues = getOnboardRecords(<ID>);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...onboardValues.entries()]))
```

will produce the following output for an onboarding template with two resources:

```
[["First Name",["FirstName1","FirstName2"]],["Last Name",
["LastName1","LastName2"]],["Phone Number",["xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx"]],
["E-Mail",["xxxx@xxxx.xxx","xxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"]],["Role",
["Delivery Manager","Sr. Developer"]],["Start Date",
["2021-11-01","2021-11-01"]],["End Date",["2021-11-30","2021-12-31"]],
["Vendor's Name",["xxxx","xxxxx"]],["Team",["xxxxxx]],
["New Resource ID",["xxxxxx","xxxxxx"]],
["New Resource Company E-mail",["xxxx@xxxxxx.xxx","xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx"]]]
```