# Creating a trello card from the apps script sidebar results in status code 500

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, trello

I wanted to implement the trello api into a sidebar so my team can create tickets in a more manageable way than texting.

I built the sidebar & functionality using vscode; which is also where I tested everything.

There were no problems until I moved everything to my apps script project; any submission results in `Response: 500`.

This is the code I wrote to create the card:

```
function createCard() {
    name = document.querySelector('#n').value;
    request = document.querySelector('#r').value;
    details = document.querySelector('#d').value;
    priority = document.querySelector('#high');
    idLabels = (priority.checked) ? '62a685a6ea88a630d3da970f' : '62a685b2b835cd665d8ba4ac';
    fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/cards?
        key=${key}&
        token=${token}&
        idList=${idList}&
        name=${name} - ${request}&
        desc=${details}&
        idLabels=${idLabels}`, {
            method: 'POST'
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(`Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
                return response.text();
            }).then(text => console.log(text))
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

I couldn't find anything that would prevent me from using an api in the sidebar.

This is the closest thing I could find to my current problem is right here:

[Google Apps Script to Create Confluence Page -- Results in Status Code 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308969/google-apps-script-to-create-confluence-page-results-in-status-code-500)

but this isn't using sidebar (if that even matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I remembered [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610). In this issue tracker, when `//` is used in the template literal of the Javascript on HTML service of Google Apps Script as you are using, it seems that `//` is used as the comment start.
- When I saw your following URL, I thought that `${name} - ${request}` might be required to do the URL encoding.

  ```
    `https://api.trello.com/1/cards?
            key=${key}&
            token=${token}&
            idList=${idList}&
            name=${name} - ${request}&
            desc=${details}&
            idLabels=${idLabels}`
  ```

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/cards?
    key=${key}&
    token=${token}&
    idList=${idList}&
    name=${name} - ${request}&
    desc=${details}&
    idLabels=${idLabels}`, {
        method: 'POST'
        }).then(response => {
```

#### To:

```
const encodedName = encodeURIComponent(`${name} - ${request}`);
const url = `https:\/\/api.trello.com\/1\/cards?key=${key}&token=${token}&idList=${idList}&name=${encodedName}&desc=${details}&idLabels=${idLabels}`;
fetch(url, { method: 'POST' }).then(response => {
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your script, I confirmed the same issue. And, when I tested my proposed modification, I confirmed that the script worked.
- When you tested the above-modified script and an error occurs, please check the variables again.

#### Reference:

- [When `//` in template literal is used in an HTML file in the script editor, it is used as a comment start.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156139610)

Comment: That worked just as you said! I read through your reference so I understand how the url was being commented, thank you. As for the URL encoding, I thought about this when I was testing the buttons in vscode but it never failed; would this have anything to do with that: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions ?

Comment: @kanwoody Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `would this have anything to do with that: developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions ?`, when I saw "HTML Service: Restrictions", I cannot find about the template literal. So, I think that this issue might be different "HTML Service: Restrictions".